# NestJS Access HTTP request in @ResolveProperty guard?

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo, nestjs

I'm in the middle of developing a Graphql API with Nest JS (I just upgraded it to 5.0.0), in which I need to allow only certain users (by roles) to access sub-parts of queries that are public.

```
import { CanActivate, ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';

@Injectable()
export class RolesGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private readonly reflector: Reflector) {}

    canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {

        const req = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();

        const roles = this.reflector.get<string[]>('roles', context.getHandler());
        if (!roles) // if no roles specified
            return true;

        console.log(req); // Displays Query() parent result instead of HTTP Request Object

        return false;
    }
}
```

Sub-parts of queries are handled by `@ResolveProperty()` decorated functions.

Following the documentation I started using Guards, but I just found out that when using guards, in GraphQL resolvers context, the `context.switchToHttp().getRequest()` is only returning the result of the parent Query()...

I don't really know if this is an expected behavior, and if it is, if there's a way to access full express Request object from a GraphQL Guard ?